# Why does DO IP + port load site but domain + port does not? ('This site can't be reached")

Tags: dns, digital-ocean

My DNS are set to DO with registrar. A and CNAME are set to domain and 'www' alias, respectively, in DO droplet.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after stopping and restarting the droplet server, it works fine.